# How to convert String^ to float?

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have taken text from a textbox txt1 in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows 8, when i use txt1->Text, it returns the text in String^. How do I convert it to float? I want this app to run on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a .NET `System::String^`.  .NET provides some conversion functions, of which my favorite is `TryParse`.

```
float value;
String^ str;
if (System::Single::TryParse(str, value)) {
    /* ok, use value */
}
else {
    /* problem : str isn't numeric */
}
```